# Use of "es" in "Ich mag es, grossartige Kunstwerke zu bewundern."

Tags: sentence-structure

I was reading a sentence in Deutsch

> Ich mag es, grossartige Kunstwerke zu bewundern.

I can translate this roughly to "*I like to admire great works of art.*"

Now, I know that there is an infinitive clause present with the  "zu bewundern", but I can't seem to find a reasonable reason for why we need the "es" after "Ich mag".

I would have constructed the sentence as

> Ich mag, grossartige Kunstwerke zu bewundern.

What is the reason for es?

Answer (score 2):

Without the *es*, you could say

> Ich mag großartige Kunstwerke bewundern.

This one uses *mögen* as a modal verb. Perfectly okay.

> Ich mag (an mir), dass ich großartige Kunstwerke bewundere.

The problem with this phrase is if you don't say who you like (leaving out *es*), you tell that you like yourself, and the object clause gives a reason for that self-praise. There's an implicit *an mir* inserted.

To avoid that, you need an accusative object. But it's not enough, you also have to refrain from the object clause above, which has *ich* as a subject and therefore, praises yourself. Instead, you need an infinitive clause which refers to *es* instead of *ich*:

> Ich mag es, großartige Kunstwerke zu bewundern.

Now you like something other than yourself. The action of looking at great pieces of art.

Comment: *Ich liebe (es) meine Haare (zu) färben* is talking about myself, is it? Without the words in parathesis, it would sound straight up ungrammatical to me. Is that just me? It could use a gerund "das Haare Färben" and ... wow, this one is tricky. It's a frequent question here, so I'm not gonna wax any more about it.

Comment: You could also, but shouldn't say "Ich mag das Großartigekunstwerkebwundern" and then you are pretty quickly at "Ich mag, dass".

Comment: My answer is about the phrase in question, not some arbitrary other phrase.

Comment: that seems to be your excuse every time doubt about your answer crops up (that's the second time now).

Comment: Excuse me, but I don't think I need to come up with excuses when I answered the thing in question correctly.

Comment: The problem is, you haven't given a motivation to go from your first example to the second. In all fairness, I don't think that relative sentences are an easy explanation, and I'm very torn about that being a natural step.

Comment: It's not a relative clause. It's an object clause lead by *dass*. That's what an infinitive clause replaces.

Comment: You see I could use an explanation, but *that's what it is* is not an explanation, so long I don't care about name-definitions.

Comment: By the way, if "Kunstwerke zu bewundern" is an infinitive clause, what is "Kunstwerke bewundern"? gerund?

Comment: *Mögen* is a modal verb. It takes a bare infinitive. As stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wen oder was magst du? Es.
Who or what do you like? Es.

e.g. I'm playing basketball. I'm enjoying *it*.

You can use `es` like a 'pronoun' for verbs

Answer (score 1):

Correctly you would say:

> Ich bewundere (gerne) großartige Kunstwerke. Ich mag es.

Then you can ask yourself what "es" is all the same as in English, where it is a frequent question (but the ones I saw didn't have a satisfying answer, so I'm not going through the trouble of searching). If I recall correctly, *it* has been dubbed the [indefinite pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_pronoun).

In you example however, it is definitely directed at the non-finite verb ([Infinitivgruppe](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitivgruppe), and at that works pretty much like the definite article *das*, which rhymes so much that the best explanation I can offer is confusion of the two, because it's pretty much indistinguishable in speech "Ich mag's, großart ...".